# jQuery Alert working in HTML, not working when added to SharePoint CEWP

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

It works on my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JustJill54/XFaaG/11/, but does not when I add jQuery code to CEWP.
(FYI. I am only putting jQuery in CEWP for proof of concept.) 
Only difference when I view src in the result on the fiddle, is Window.Load() event is there, so I tried adding that event to my CEWP, but alert still does not work.

Here's code from CEWP

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr.reqDet").hide();
    $("tr.anon").hide();
    $("tr.actDet").hide();

    // Attach to the focusout event of the select, if that's when
    // you want to check the value
    $("select[title='organizationalElement']").focusout(function() {
        // Now see if it's the value you want
        if ($(this).val() === 'idk') {
            alert("If no organizational element is selected, additional time may be required to route this request");
        } //close if
    $("select[title='requestType']").change(function() {
        $(".reqDet").toggle($(this).val() !== "");
    }); //close requestType
    $("select[title='anonymous']").change(function() {
        $(".anon").toggle();
    }); //close anonymous
    $("select[title='action']").change(function() {
        $(".actDet").toggle($(this).val() !== "");
    }); //close action
    }); //close select.focusout
}); //close doc.ready
}); //close window.load
</script>
```

UPDATE: I have commented out all of my logic and just tried to get AN alert to show when the page loads and I still have not been able to get it to work.

UPDATE2: I have created an .html page with same controls as my SharePoint page, and added jQuery script to show alert on page load, and even that one is working, but .aspx page with SharePoint:FormField controls is not working.

UPDATE3: I have referenced a javascript tutorial and revised my script. The main differences are that the NOT EQUAL operators have been changed to != instead, and I have commented out the Window.load event. Here is my revised script:

```
//$(window).load(function(){

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("tr.reqDet").hide();
    $("tr.anon").hide();
    $("tr.actDet").hide();

    $("select[title='organizationalElement']").focusout(function() {

        if ($(this).val() === 'idk') {
            alert("If no organizational element is selected, additional time may be required to route this request");
        } // close if

    $("select[title='requestType']").change(function() {
        $(".reqDet").toggle($(this).val() != "");
    }); //close requestType.change

    $("select[title='anonymous']").change(function(){
      $(".anon").toggle();
    }); //close anonymous.change

    $("select[title='action']").change(function(){
        $(".actDet").toggle($(this).val()!= "");
    }); // close action.change

    });//close select.focusout

}); // close doc.ready
//}); // close window.load
```

UPDATE4: I used firebug to get the val of the selector, and realized it is not returning 'idk' (as specified by SP's list item's value), but returning "I don't know" instead. Which raises another issue/reminds me I will need to escaping the apostrophe (') in don't. Anyways, still working out the kinks...

UPDATE5: @Janis- I am not able to see my script on the script tab in firebug... So I guess that mean's it isn't being executed.

BTW. Here's the state of the script after UPDATE4.

```
$(window).load(function(){

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("tr.reqDet").hide();
    $("tr.anon").hide();
    $("tr.actDet").hide();

    $("select[title='organizationalElement']").focusout(function() {

        if ($(this).val() === "I don\'t know") {
            alert("If no organizational element is selected, additional time may be required to route this request");
        } // close if

    $("select[title='requestType']").change(function() {
        $(".reqDet").toggle($(this).val() != "");
    }); //close requestType.change

    $("select[title='anonymous']").change(function(){
      $(".anon").toggle();
    }); //close anonymous.change

    $("select[title='action']").change(function(){
        $(".actDet").toggle($(this).val()!= "");
    }); // close action.change

    });//close select.focusout

}); // close doc.ready
}); // close window.load
```

Any idea why? I thought I was using pretty general events that are always called (doc.ready, window.load).

UPDATE6: Geez...FINALLY! Guess the 6th time's the charm. I'm definitely going to fill everyone in on what worked for me....
Anyways, revised script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).load(function(){  
  $(document).ready(function(){      
     $("tr.reqDet").hide();     
     $("tr.anon").hide();     
     $("tr.actDet").hide();      
   $("select[title='organizationalElement']").focusout(function() {          
     if ($(this).val() === "I don\'t know") {             
        alert("If no organizational element is selected, additional time may be required to route this request");         
     } // close if      
      $("select[title='requestType']").change(function() {         
        $(".reqDet").toggle($(this).val() != "");     
      }); //close requestType.change      
      $("select[title='anonymous']").change(function(){       
        $(".anon").toggle();     
      }); //close anonymous.change      
      $("select[title='action']").change(function(){         
        $(".actDet").toggle($(this).val()!= "");     
      }); // close action.change      
   });//close select.focusout  
  }); // close doc.ready 
}); // close window.load 
</script>
```

Instead of pasting directly into CEWP, I have it uploaded as .js file to a folder I created called SiteAssets (in the event we migrate to SPD2010), and am calling said file ...js via the CEWP's content link. Used firebug to verify script was being loaded.

So, some things I've learned about getting this jQuery script to work for me in my SP page-

1. Do not assume you know what val is being returned-- use console tab of firebug to get EXACT results
2. Check your syntax
3. Even when referencing jQuery code in a ...js file, make sure that it starts w/ requisite  tags, o.w. you may end up with your script being inserted as text at the bottom of the page
   Hope this helps!

Comment: in Firebug, can you see your custom script (the code you just pasted in here)?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the above script to a text file and save it in a document library.  Then edit the CEWP and add the url of the script file in the reference link.  SharePoint likes to strip/destroy code if it is input directly into the CEWP.

Comment: I saved the script to a doc lib (/SiteAssets/1/orgAlert_rev1.js), and used the content link to reference the file (../../SiteAssets/1/orgAlert_rev1.js). Unfortunately, no alert.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to view source and see if jQuery is referenced sucessfully and
   that your code is actually there.
2. Further you can use debugging tool such as Firebug or chrome
   inspector or internet explorer developer tools, if you will, and set breakpoints to see if code actually gets executed, if there are any errors that prevent it from executing. If you don't know how to use them, learn them, it will be a long way and time saver towards debugging such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your fiddle out, and find that there, you are doing a window.load magic, but just remove it!

```
 $(window).load(function(){
```

I have tried it in your fiddle and over my testing SharePoint, and it works. Just remove that line and its closing tags.}

*** not sure this gonna do the magic but it works for me, should do it for You ***

Comment: I had tried that before posting, and it did not work. I tried again today, and it still does not work.

Comment: Try to add your jQuery reference to your master page, then your script will run once your DOM is loaded.

Comment: By jQuery reference, you mean <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> line? Added it to master in the <head> and closed site, emptied cache, went to page, and still no alert.